# Run Nagios check_mk plugin once, instead of per host

Tags: monitoring, nagios, check-mk

I've written a `check_mk` Nagios plugin that is monitoring a REST API. I only want a single instance of this service/script on the entire monitoring service, not a service instance per host.

However, when I add the script to the `/local/lib/nagios/plugin` directory and configure a classical activate & passive monitoring check in WATO, it creates a service for each host.

Is this possible or am I doing this the wrong way?

Comment: Which WATO folder do you configure that check?

Answer (score 0):

Dropping scripts in `/opt/omd/sites/{site}/local/lib/nagios/plugins`, then defining custom checks in `/opt/omd/sites/{site}/etc/check_mk/conf.d/wato/rules.mk` is how I ended up having a single check.